# Variable not defined error, when trying to call a variable defined in a .h file

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, clr

Already linked all my files to "Pusi.h"

declared variables here "Pusi.h"

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {

int strength = 0;
int  dexterity = 0;
int  money = 0;
int smarts = 0;
int magic = 0;
int health = 0;
int Belligerent = 0;
std::string  Politics;

strength -= 2;
money += 2;
smarts += 1;
this->Hide();
Pusi_intro^ good = gcnew Pusi_intro(this);
good->ShowDialog();
}
};
```

Tried to increased the value of the  variables int  dexterity, int  money = 0, int smarts,"Pusi_intro1.h"
by

```
dexterity += 1;

money += 1;

smarts += 1;
```

that didn't work.

error said dexterity, money, smarts not decleared

So I tried

```
Pusi_intro(int money) {
            
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int& m = money;
        Pusi_intro(int dexeterity) {
            
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int& d = dexeterity;
        Pusi_intro(int smarts) {
            
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        int& sm = smarts;
```

that didn't work either got the same error and a new error that told me the `reference wasn't declared`

than I had another thought maybe the error is because of the line I declared it

so I tried

```
public:

int& sm;


int& d;


int& m;

Pusi_intro(int smarts)

 {

sm = smarts
InitializeComponent();


}

Pusi_intro(int dexterity) {
d = dexterity;
InitializeComponent();
}
Pusi_intro(int money) {
m = money;
InitializeComponent();
}
```

then I tried adding to the variable again and I got the same error I was getting before, im fresh out of ideas, New to programming so explanation and help is much needed and welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to tag the language as C++/CLR.  The `Object^` syntax is not C++, but Managed C++ by Microsoft.

Comment: Are you trying to access a local variable of a function from outside the function?

Comment: yes I am trying to access a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your header file you want to define prototypes only not the entire function.
And then in your cpp file you want to do:

```
#include .../all other libraries go here
#include "header.h"/Your header file
class_name::prototype{
//do stuff
}
```

And than you want to create a tester file like so:

```
int main(){
    classname variablename;
    classname.methodname();
    return 0;
}
```